# Redirect URL to URL with unicode characters (emoji)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, unicode, emoji

In the first place, I want to create a new homepage URL. So instead of `www.example.com` my new homepage (base) should be `www.example.com/abc`.

So no matter what the user types as an URL, for example `www.example.com/blabla`, we need to redirect him to `www.example.com/abc/blablabla`.

If I am correct, the following will do that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc.*
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /abc/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now comes the problem.

My new base isn't `abc`, but . The URL valid value of this 'globe' is `%F0%9F%8C%90`. So you would think it's easy and replace all  `abc`'s in the .htaccess snippet above and your done, but unfortunately that isnt't the case.

Hope someone can help me out.

Regards,
TK

---

**UPDATE:**

Going to `www.example.com` results in loop that looks like `www.example.nl/%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0%25F0FC0`.

Notice that besides the loop, the icon is not showed as well..

In my example the .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%F0%9F%8C%90.*
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /%F0%9F%8C%90$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, I fixed the icon part by adding `NE` as an flag and backslashing the unicode characters..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%F0%9F%8C%90.*
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /\%F0\%9F\%8C\%90/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

So:

```
www.example.com
```

now results in

```
www.example.com////////.....
```

But still got the loop.. :(... anyone got an idea?

Comment: Can you show the code that *isn't* working and describe what exactly is  happening?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can [input that emoji *directly*](http://hastebin.com/yaxabisoso.apache) into Sublime Text (replacing `abc`), and it works like a charm. No need to encode a thing. Must say, this is quite fascinating indeed. Weird, but fascinating.

Comment: @MikeRockett The reason that it's working in your example, is because the website is already interpreting the unicode as an icon, where Apache does not work like that..

Comment: No, it is working on my development server. Apache is picking it up as a Unicode character just fine.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've set up a test link for you: http://rockett.pw/.unicode/testing, which will redirect to `http://rockett.pw/.unicode//testing` (producing a 404 as there is no handler, of course).

Comment: Weird. Is the file saved in unicode? (UTF8)

Comment: @MikeRockett The weird thing is that you do not have the loop :S...

Comment: I don't think you can actually use those encoded versions in htaccess - not really sure, though. Those characters are normal, I noticed as well. If you change it to `testing.php`, you'll see the page loads up fine. Maybe just create the file using Sublime, and do your other stuff in PHPStorm.

Comment: @MikeRockett Lol, I got it working. Its PhpStorm that is messing it up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER:**

Just replace `abc` with the actual icon . Make sure you do this using an editor that can handle these unicode icons... PhpStorm can't, but TextMate or Sublime works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ works fine, too ^^ maybe it helps.